# angular 4 - Optimize the multiple HTTP request on keyup event

Tags: angular, typescript

I know when I use the keyup event it means new http request. Is theres a way that it only request once? because I am thinking If I type my name "edizon" the http request will be :

```
e
ed
edi
ediz
edizo
edzion

<input type="text" (keyup)="func()">
```

can I optimize it and request once only? I am curious about speed.

Comment: You can't just request once since you don't have a mechanism to tell if a particular keyup is the LAST one. But you can defer it and only send once request in a while. Check it out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935424/how-to-achieve-a-debounce-service-on-input-keyup-event-in-angular2-with-rxjs

Comment: I have a question, everytime I type it have a request right, the first request must finish first before it display the complete word I type? I think I use async

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to achieve a debounce service on input keyup event in angular2 with rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935424/how-to-achieve-a-debounce-service-on-input-keyup-event-in-angular2-with-rxjs)