# how to stop array.filter() function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

Am using custom search filter

HtML

```
 <input type="text" pInputText class="ui-widget ui-text" [(ngModel)]
 ="gloablFilterValue" (ngModelChange)="splitCustomFilter()" placeholder="Find" />
```

I am using `ngModelChange()` event on search box

---

```js
globalSearch(realData, searchText, columns) {
        searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
        return realData.filter(function (o) {
            return columns.some(function (k) {
                return o[k].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
            });
        });
    }

    splitCustomFilter() {
    let columns =  
   ['PartNoCompleteWheel', 'DescriptionCompleteWheel', 'PartNoTyre', 'DescriptionTyre', 'PartNoRim', 'DescriptionRim','DeletedDateFromKDPStr', 'DateFromKDPStr', 'Status'];
   this.tyreAndRimList = this.globalSearch(this.tyreAndRimList, this.gloablFilterValue, columns); 
    }
```

The `this.tyreAndRimList` list of values for the columns which is mentioned in a `column` variable.

**Problem**

The filter is working good! But the main problem is filter performance is very poor while the record count is huge(more than 100 rows per every column)

**When**

The filter is working good if am entering a single character (like `a`). But when I was typing the character continuously the browser is hanging. the reason is the filter has been firing every typing on the filter box(because of am using `ngModelChange()// onchange()` event)

**What I want**

I want to stop filtering if the user typing continuously on the search box. Once the user has stop the typing then only I need to start filtering.

**What I did**

I have tried to handle this by using `setTimeout()`. But it just wait the filter call for a second. It is working if the user entered just 2 or 3 character's continuously. But if the user typing  more than 7 or 8 or above character's, it continues to hang the browser. because of many filter callbacks are processing on the same time.

```
 setTimeout(() => //code of filtering ,1000);
```

**Question**

How to stop filtering while user continuously entering value and start the filtering once the user has been stop the typing?

I am working in angular-2 and typescript. But this question is not related with only for `angularjs` or `angular`  or `JavaScript` or `typescript` because of I want an idea not a solution.  So I'll add those all  tags for this question. Don't remove it. Thanks

Comment: You can't stop a `filter` before it's done. You can, on the other hand, use a `for` loop that you can `break`. Other possibility : [debounce your filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935424/how-to-achieve-a-debounce-service-on-input-keyup-event-in-angular2-with-rxjs)

Comment: you need to [debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) the event.

Comment: So look at debounce and also if filtered, there is no need to filter the entire list when they typed one more character, just filter the filtered set.

Comment: Of course debounce, but on top of that you could probably optimise the code some more. For example you could(assuming the text is static) make a single concatenated string during init of all the cells per row. And then only check the concatenated string per row. That way you can already skip looping all columns+strtolower in your filter.

Comment: Try to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36849347/356380

Comment: @Whisher Nice! I'll take a look at that. and try that.

Comment: If this process is a core feature, and debouncing isn't enough, consider delegating the computation to a WebWorker so it doesn't tie up your main thread..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to achieve a debounce service on input keyup event in angular2 with rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935424/how-to-achieve-a-debounce-service-on-input-keyup-event-in-angular2-with-rxjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have complete it by using `Subject` to `debounceTime`.

```
private subject = new Subject<string>()
ngOnInit() {
        this.subject.debounceTime(300).subscribe(inputText => {
        this.gloablFilterValue = inputText;
        this.splitCustomFilter();   // filter method  
        });    
    }
```

Now when I change the value in `this.gloablFilterValue` object by using change event. It just waiting for the end of event completion.

Answer (score 2):

Debounce the function. See how underscore does it here: [Function Debouncing with Underscore.js](https://davidwalsh.name/function-debounce).

You would then generate a debounced version of your function like this:

```
var globalSearchDebounced = _.debounce(globalSearch, 100, false);
```

It will only call after the user has stopped typing for at least one second.

Comment: An alternative to this solution would be making the form reactive, subscribing to the input's value changes, then applying the rxjs debounce operator. Could also add additional operators such as filter to enforce a minimum number of characters before executing the array filter.

Comment: You can't "just copy 14 lines". There's still a license with terms that have to be followed when you use part of the code.

Comment: @IngoBürk true enough. The offending sentence is removed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to interrupt the `Array.filter` method. Based on what you need you could handle this like this:

```
let timerId = null

function handleChange() {
  if(timerId) {
    clearTimeout(timerId)
  }

  timerId = setTimeout(() => /* Array.filter(...) */, 1000)
}
```

**Explanation**

Have a variable which will contain the `timerId` returned from the `setTimeout` function. Every time the model get changed the `handleChange` function will be called (in this example). The function checks if the variable which contains the `timerId` is set and contains a `timerId`, when the variable contains the `timerId` the `clearTimeout` function will be called to clear the previous timeout after that the handleChange creates a new timeout and assigns the `timerId` (returned from the `setTimeout` function) to the variable.

- Documentation for [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)
- Documentation for [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout)

Answer (score 1):

Without underscore, and without a Timeout (that will trigger the whole Angular lifecycle by the way), you can use an Observable with the async pipe and a debounce.

In your global search function :

```
return Observable.of(/* filter here and return the filtered array */).debounceTime(1000)
```

In your list (that has to be somewhere I guess)

```
<list-item *ngFor="let x of myFilteredResults | async">...</list-item>
```

Comment: Error; property `of` does not exist for the type of` Observable`

Comment: `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';`

Comment: `import 'rxjs/Rx';` (this is bad practice to do this one, but it will allow you to test if it works as you want)