# How to debounce a Keyboard Input (keyUp) in Angular and intoduce Subjects/ Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm making a app for myself that should cover "real world" scenarios. I am currently trying to use the Material Autocomplete in a form so that when a user adds/inserts a value to the input the `keyup` event calls a method that makes an API call that returns some data and I use this to populate an Autocomplete (I have 3 in my page). 
What I have works but

a) it feels very inefficient

b) Not the best implementation (or the Angular way and

c) it is missing a debounce to prevent the user overloading the server with API calls.

Here I have my form from my HTML template with 3 input that all have a method that captures the `keyup` event. Each input has a `mat-autocomplete` in it that iterates through values that match the user input (so if the user inputs "Col" in the company input values like "Cola Inc", "Columbia University", "Color Clothing Inc").

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="assignmentForm">
  <div>
    <input type="text" matInput placeholder="User" formControlName="worker" name="worker" (keyup)="getTags($event)" [matAutocomplete]="workerTemplate">
    <mat-autocomplete #workerTemplate="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let worker of workerTags" [value]="worker">{{ worker.displayName}}</mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Company" formControlName="company" name="company" (keyup)="getTags($event)" [matAutocomplete]="companyTemplate">
    <mat-autocomplete #companyTemplate="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let company of companyTags" [value]="company">{{company.displayName}}</mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Department" formControlName="department" name="department" (keyup)="getTags($event)" [matAutocomplete]="departmentTemplate">
    <mat-autocomplete #departmentTemplate="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let department of departmentTags" [value]="department">{{department.displayName}}</mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the method that takes the user input and calls the API then populates the correct `mat-option` array (I've reduced a lot of my component code for ease of reading)

```
        public companyTags: any[];
        public departmentTags: any[];
        public workerTags: any[];

        constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

        public getTags(ev: KeyboardEvent): void {
        // if the user presses backspace the value is "" and all results are returned (to set limit)
        if((<HTMLInputElement>ev.target).value !== '') {
    // the api method takes 3 args type, value and limit, it returns an object array         
    this.apiService.getTags((<HTMLInputElement>ev.target).name, (<HTMLInputElement>ev.target).value, 3).subscribe((res) => {
            this.clearAllTags();
            // as the target name is used in the tag array name we can use interpolation
            // rather than a horrible if then else
            this[`${(<HTMLInputElement>ev.target).name}Tags`] = res;
          });
        } else {
          this.clearAllTags();
        }
      }

      /**
       * Clear all specific Tag Arrays
       */
      public clearAllTags(): void {
        this.companyTags = null;
        this.departmentTags = null;
        this.workerTags = null;
      }
```

I'm wondering the following: Firstly, can I make the form more streamlined by using the AutoComplete once or sharing it between the three inputs as I only show one autocomplete at once time? Secondly how do I use or introduce a debounce here? Should I be using RxJS and Observables and if so should I have 3 Observables or can I listen / subscribe to all three inputs using one Observable? I've done some reading on this but I am a little confused.

If my question seems badly worded please state so and I shall rewrite my question. I am wanting to learn Angular the best way. Many thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: I use the first result to the search for 'javascript debounce function'. But it's basically just a setTimeout.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935424/how-to-achieve-a-debounce-service-on-input-keyup-event-in-angular2-with-rxjs/41965515